# Intercept an Ajax request and convert it Jsonp request with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp

I have an app that makes many ajax calls to a rest API, those calls are triggered in many differents js files.

I'd like to interecept all those requests, and re-send as jsonp request (for cross-origin purposes).

I could simply set dataType:"jsonp" inside $.ajax(..), but there are too many js files for this approach, so, I need to do this with an interceptor to avoid editing all those files.

I've tried using beforeSend:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        if (someFilter(settings))
            return;
        settings.dataType = "jsonp";
    }
});
```

But this doesn't add others params like 'callback' nor the callback url parameter as $.ajax(..) does.

$.ajax(..) automatically append all necessary params when using "jsonp" dataType, using its .done() function as the jsonp callback.

Can I do this with an interceptor?

I've thought maybe I could make a new jsonp request from the intercepted one, canceling this last one after extracting the relevant information (url, method, done callback, fail callback, etc..). But I'd like a better solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a little confusing, how would you resend something from the clients browser, and to where?

Comment: I want to redirect all ajax calls to another server (with a different domain). This can be done using beforeSend, editing the destinarion request URL in the settings. But in order to do this I need use to use jsonp, because all those request are json.
With resend a request **I mean to take the original ajax request, process the request to create a new one and send this new modified request instead of  the first one**.